# Rails undefined method `encode' for CSV:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm trying to generate CSV file from active admin logs. To do so I'm using below method:

```
require 'csv'

def call
  CSV.generate(col_sep: ';', headers: LOG_HEADERS, encoding: 'UTF-8') do |csv|
    PaperTrail::Version.all.each do |version|
      old_data_value = version.changeset.present? ? version.changeset.map { |k, v| k + ": #{v[0]}" } : ''
      new_data_value = version.changeset.present? ? version.changeset.map { |k, v| k + ": #{v[1]}" } : ''

      csv << [version.created_at.in_time_zone('CET'),
              version.event,
              AdminUser.find(version.whodunnit).email,
              old_data_value,
              new_data_value]
    end
  end

  send_data CSV.encode('UTF-8'), type: 'text/csv; charset=UTF-8; header=present', disposition: 'attachment; filename=admin_logs.csv'
end
```

But when I'm trying to execute this method I'm getting an error:

`` undefined method `encode' for CSV:Class ``

So the problem is in this line: `send_data CSV.encode` - I tried to change it to `csv.encode` instead of `CSV.encode` but I'm getting another error:

```
undefined local variable or method `csv' for #<AdminLogData::CsvAdminLogGenerator:0x00007fedbeb95ba0>
Did you mean?  CSV
```

Comment: Try to assign result of `CSV.generate` to variable and then use it in send_data. Something like `result = CSV.generate...` and then `send_data result.encode('UTF-8')...`

Comment: @BartoszBonisławski I'm getting new error: `undefined method 'send_data'`

Comment: `send_data` is method used in Ruby on Rails controllers. Where are you trying to call it?

Comment: I'm using it in a separate service

Comment: I'd suggest to return result of `CSV.generate` from this service and then use `send_data` with result of that service if you want to serve it over http. You can save this to file or do whatever you want. You just cannot `send_data` from service

Comment: You were right, when I moved only CSV.generate logic to the separate service and use `send_data` on controller it worked!